# How to create new user when configuration is locked using "Configuration Read-only"

Tags: drupal-8, pantheon

We have a Drupal 8 site hosted at Pantheon and the site configuration is locked via the "Configuration Read-only" module.

I created a local clone of the site using git and added a new user but when I do a `git status` it shows my branch as being in sync with the master. With this said, it doesn't look like the newly added user was written to any of the config YAML files.

So, I suspect that I will need to export the database from my local and import it to Pantheon - but this doesn't seem like the correct process or safest method. Can someone please confirm as I haven't found any resources applicable to this scenario and want to ensure that I'm following best practice?

Comment: [FAQ on how to question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)
Formatting please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Users are Entities and as such are stored in the database, not in configuration.

If you want to synchronize your users across different environments then you'll have to look into a way to retrieve db backups from Pantheon and import them into a different environment *or* look into a module to sync the User entities. I found the [content_sync](https://www.drupal.org/project/content_sync) module from a quick Google search, but have not used it and cannot guarantee that it will work/ fulfill your requirements.

Comment: I see. So while the "Configuration Read-Only" module prohibits changes to configuration, which includes users, users aren't stored in configuration. Someone shoot me! Thanks a bunch for the clarification. Hopefully this helps someone else.

Comment: Just to clarify, the changes in configuration that pertain to users are generally role definitions and which permissions the roles have - the actual users themselves are stored in the database. Hope that helps!